# How to solve '_tkinter' module not found?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I've been learning GUI in python with tkinter, but my very first code is not working and the error says `modulenotfounderror: '_tkinter'` not found.

I've installed python-tk as well as python3-tk packages.

NOTE: Please note the underscore with tkinter while answering.
How to solve this problem?

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
Label(root, text="Hello World")
Label.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: what system - Windows, Linux, Mac ? Python should have preinstalled `tkinter` but on some Linux servers - which don't use GUI - I saw Python without Tkinter. Tkinter uses language `tcl` and its module `tk` so you may have to install it too. On Linux Ubuntu you install `tcl/tk` using `apt`, not `pip`.

Comment: First of all `Label.pack()` is not how you pack widgets use `Label(root, text="Hello World").pack()` or `L = Label(root, text=' ')` , `L.pack()` but this won't fix the error you're getting, tkinter is a build-in library so it might have to do with python you installed. Try python -m tkinter in the cmd if you get any errors reinstall python.

Comment: Linux is the OS I'm using

Comment: Which Linux distribution? Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

reinstall python as python has been upgraded and some packages got their names changed.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
Label(root, text="Hello World").pack()
root.mainloop()
```